# Adding item to index: QuerySet no attribute save

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

I am trying to get a field to be added to my index when it is changed.

The code below is updating the index correctly, but actual model does not get updated. Also, I get a traceback error (provided via link at bottom).

I get the error:
`'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'save'`.

I have provided the traceback via a link below.

### # models.py

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=5000, blank=True)
    taglevel = models.IntegerField("Tag level", null=True, blank=True)

    def to_search(self):
        tags = self.id
        if tags:
            queryset = Item.objects.filter(tag=tags)
            for object in queryset:
                object.save()
        return queryset

class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("Title", max_length=10000, blank=True)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True)

    def get_grouped_tags(self):
        tag = self.tag.order_by('taglevel')
        grouped_tags = {
            tag_level: [
                { 'name': tag_of_level.name, 'taglevel': tag_of_level.taglevel, }
                for tag_of_level in tags_of_level
            ] for tag_level, tags_of_level
            in groupby(tag, lambda tag: tag.taglevel)
        }
        return grouped_tags

    def to_search(self):
        d = {
            "tags": self.get_grouped_tags(),
            "title": self.title
        }
        return ItemIndex(meta={'id': self.id}, **d)

    def indexing(self):
        obj = ItemIndex(
            meta={'id': self.id},
            title=self.title,
            tag=self.get_grouped_tags(),
        )
        obj.save()
        return obj.to_dict(include_meta=True)

def update_search(instance, **kwargs):
    instance.to_search().save()

def remove_from_search(instance, **kwargs):
    instance.to_search().delete()

post_save.connect(update_search, sender=Item)
post_save.connect(update_search, sender=Tag)
pre_delete.connect(remove_from_search, sender=Item)
pre_delete.connect(remove_from_search, sender=Tag)
m2m_changed.connect(update_search, sender=Item.tag.through)
```

### # search.py

```
class ItemIndex(DocType):
    title = String()
    class Meta:
        index = 'Item-index'

def bulk_indexing():
    ItemIndex.init()
    es = Elasticsearch()
    bulk(client=es, actions=(b.indexing() for b in models.Item.objects.all().iterator()))

def _search(title):
    s = Search().filter('term', title=title.text)
    response = s.execute()
    return response
```

## Traceback

http://dpaste.com/1FGGKBF

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that signal executes this line

```
instance.to_search().save()
```

But for your `Tag` model's `to_search` returns queryset

```
def to_search(self):
    tags = self.id
    if tags:
        queryset = Item.objects.filter(tag=tags)
        for object in queryset:
            object.save()
    return queryset #  <- here
```

And that is why you are getting this error. You should return either `ItemIndex` as you do for `Item` model's `to_search`, or maybe return self.